# magento multistore products import from another store

Tags: magento-1.8, category, multistore, products

There are two stores in my magento website. One is English and Another is  German. There are categories and products in English Store. I want all those same products to be shown in German with same categories but when I use the English Default Root Category for my German Store, it does not show my theme. So I have created two different root categories but the categories and products for both stores are same. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't show my theme"?

Comment: I mean to say that I have set two different templates for two different stores. The home page of store-2 is picking stylesheet of theme-2 but the products pages of store-2 are picking stylesheet of theme-1.

Comment: How did you setup your theme?

Comment: I have installed them using magento connect. They are in the magento root folder and I have created a sub-directory for my another store where I have only copied index.php and .htaccess files